# What Configuration Management tools are available that doesn't use Linux?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-server, configuration-management

I have started working in a project that uses Windows tech stack exclusively (ASP.NET, Windows Servers, C#, Hyper-V, TFS, TeamCity, etc.)

I need to implement [Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management). Usually I would do it with Ansible, Puppet, Chef or similar... but they don't want to have a Linux Puppet Master (or equivalent).

The objective is **installing required software and change configuration settings** from a vanilla Windows Server VM created with Hyper-v **to** install software from scripts in a repeatable way like  *IIS, .NET framework 3.5, RabbitMQ, add some entries to machine.config and in general whatever is needed.* Targets are running Windows Servers 2012 SP1.

AFAIK I have some options

- PowerShell DSC
- Plain PowerShell scripts
- Chef Solo
- Puppet MasterLess?

So my questions are:

**What options do I have away from Linux?**

**Which Configuration Management tool is more Microsoft/Windows/TeamCity friendly?**

NOTE: I prefer opensource / free if possible but it is not a must.